# Powershell - Is it possible to pipe within a pipe? - Get-AzureADDevices based on Get-AzureAdUser list

Tags: powershell

Hope you guys can help me with this, I'm a bit stuck on this.  I'm trying to get a list of ADDevices that belong to the users in a specific office grouping.  Currently I have

```
Get-AzureADUser -all | where {$_.accountenabled -eq $true -and $_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName -eq "Waltham"}
```

to get the users, but I'm trying to run

```
get-azureaddevice -all $true
```

off of that and it's erroring out.

The end goal is to figure out which devices are properly Intune enrolled and which need to be addressed.

Comment: What do you mean by "off of that"? I don't think a "pipe within a pipe" is going to help you here - you'll need to fetch user-device registrations with something like `Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredUser` if you want to filter devices based on users. This of course won't tell you which devices need to be "addressed", because it'll only show you the devices that _are_ configured.

Comment: `Get-AzureADDevice -All $true` will query all devices on AAD. If you want to pipe this cmdlet with `Get-AzureADUser` it should work by removing `-All $true` so: `Get-AzureADUser -All | where {....} | Get-AzureADDevice`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for providing that cmdlet - it sent me down a rabbit hole which got me to where i needed to be!